# Flutter googleMap direction URL & streetView not launching in Android 11

Tags: flutter, google-maps, url, google-street-view

I have StreetView links like this:
https://goo.gl/maps/A2gCzkRGJwMzhpwx5

And directions links like this:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=ScottMonument&destination_place_id=GhIJ8_3UeOn5S0ARlUOLbOeLCcA&travelmode=walking

Some others are encoded instead with lat/lon co-ordinates:

```
_directionsURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination="
                          + (presentLocation.latLng.latitude.toString() + ","
                              + presentLocation.latLng.longitude.toString()) + "&travelmode=walking";
```

Most importantly I have suggested walking routes encoding like this:
https://goo.gl/maps/H7DzznQYZvJmNZQa8

And NONE of them work!

They did in the emulator, beautifully, they would launch and the Googlemaps app would catch the URL and redirect.  But on my phone on Android 11, the button simply pulses and nothing happens, no attempt to launch anything.

I LOVED doing it this way because I thought when the app was released on iOS, it would force Googlemaps to open in the browser, rather than have to launch apple-maps, where the proposed walks, with multiple waypoints, wouldn't route correctly.

But alas it won't work.  Or is there a way around it?

Failing that I suppose the best solution is some kind of Flutter intent to open the Googlemap app / Apple maps.

Is that possible with multiple way point walks like so: https://goo.gl/maps/H7DzznQYZvJmNZQa8 ?

- What would be the best way to launch Street Views so they work on
  both iOS & Android?
- Maybe use the long URL copy & pasted from
  Chrome's search bar, rather than Google's elegant shortened versions?
- Would that be resilient or could google change it with a imagery
  update?

Thanks!

Sam.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to launch Street Views so they work on both
> iOS & Android?

Do you mean a widget to show street view?

If yes, try [flutter_google_street_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#web) that a flutter plugin supports web, android and iOS.

And I am the owner of [flutter_google_street_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#web). The usage steps shown below.

Usage Steps:

1. Get an API key at https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/.
2. Specify your API key to your code.([Web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#web), [Android](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#ios), [iOS](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#ios))
3. Create FlutterGoogleStreetView widget and the sample code show below.

   ```
   StreetViewController? streetViewController;

   FlutterGoogleStreetView(
     initPos: LatLng(25.0780892, 121.5753234),
     onStreetViewCreated: (StreetViewController controller) async {
      //save controller for late using
      streetViewController = controller;
      //change position by controller
      controller.setPosition(position: LatLng(37.769263, -122.450727))
    }
   )
   ```
4. Done and control **FlutterGoogleStreetView** by **streetViewController**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you affiliated with this package? If so, you need to disclose that. Otherwise, you risk having your reputation reduced or even account deleted for spamming.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks for your kind reminder. I am the owner of flutter_google_street_view, and I have disclose the information.